# How can I run an exe file from Python 3.x Windows Service?

Tags: python, windows, executable, popen

This is very frustrating. I am trying to launch any EXE from a **WINDOWS SERVICE**. I'm using Python 3.5 and Win10. I created the service inheriting from `win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework` as I have seen in many examples on the Internet

I've tried it with `os.startfile()`, `subprocess.call()`, `subprocess.Popen()` and `os.system()` and always with the same result. The application's executable (that I launched from the service) is appearing as a subthread (subprocess) no like main process and you don't see any windows (GUI).

It doesn't matter if it's a program compiled by me or any executable like Windows Notepad.exe

```py
def main(self):
    while self.isrunning:
        try:
            # Check if subprocess exists:
            s = subprocess.check_output('tasklist', shell=True)
            if bytes("notepad.exe", 'UTF-8') not in s:
                os.startfile('notepad.exe')
```

And I've also tried:

```py
os.startfile('notepad.exe')
```

```py
results = subprocess.Popen(['notepad.exe'], close_fds=True, creationflags=DETACHED_PROCESS)
```

```py
subprocess.Popen('notepad.exe')
```

and in the other ways that I mentioned before. Same result.

The application runs like subprocess (the thread is running in the TaskManager Subprocess section) but no window is visible.

If I run the same code from a normal Python script it works perfect. The problem is doing it from the service.

Some help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't use Windows but services may have no access to desktop for security reason - they could steal your password when you write it on bank's web pageor on facebook's page. And many times services have to work when nobody is logged in so there is no desktop to display it.

Comment: Typically services execute in session 0, which is an isolated, non-interactive session. If you need to create a process in an interactive session or the console session (i.e. the session that's connected to the physical display and input devices), then you need to get the primary access token for the session via `WTSQueryUserToken` and use it to create the process via `CreateProcessAsUser`. This is at a lower level than `subprocess.Popen`. Since you're already using PyWin32, you'll likely end up using `win32security` (to enable required privileges), `win32ts`, and `win32process`.